# Variadic function and C++11, passing objects as parameters

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, cocos2d-x, marmalade

I have such trouble, when we start using new C++11, compiler (GCC) says that this code is wrong, but it works fine at older version :(

```
std::list<CCPoint> createPointArray(int count, ...) {
    CCPoint val;
    std::list<CCPoint*> arr;

    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl,count);
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        val = va_arg(vl,CCPoint*);
        arr.push_back(*val);
    }
    va_end(vl);

    return arr;
}
```

And this is the way, i'm using it:

```
createPointArray(3, &CCPoint(1.3,2.7), &CCPoint(1.5,1.75), &CCPoint(1.9,1.3))
```

Compiler tell me next:

```
Error   486 error : taking address of temporary [-fpermissive] (col 57)
```

Why is it something wrong with &CCPoint(1.3,2.7) ? How can i change this code to be workable with C++11 and older version?

P.S.: I'am using Marmalade 7.3.1, Visual Studio 2010, cocos2d-x v2.2.1

Comment: Why not simply use `createPointArray(3, CCPoint(1.3,2.7), CCPoint(1.5,1.75), CCPoint(1.9,1.3))` and `std::list<CCPoint>` everywhere?

Comment: Your code does not compile - `va_arg(vl, CCPoint*)` is a pointer so you can't assign it to `val` which is not a pointer. Then you do `*val` but `val` is not a pointer. And `val` cannot go into a list of `CCPoint *`. Post your real code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the address of a prvalue temporary is illegal (and was indeed illegal in C++03 as well).

You can use a cast to change the value category to lvalue:

```
createPointArray(3,
  &static_cast<CCPoint const&>(CCPoint(1.3,2.7)),
  &static_cast<CCPoint const&>(CCPoint(1.5,1.75)),
  &static_cast<CCPoint const&>(CCPoint(1.9,1.3)));
```

This will work in both C++03 and C++11, as the temporary objects are not destroyed until the end of the enclosing full-expression.

Because you are passing the objects by pointer to `const`, you should extract them using `va_arg(vl, CCPoint const*)`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using C++11, don't write this function in the first place. The new initializer list constructor will handle it for you:

```
std::list<CCPoint> l { CCPoint(1.3,2.7), CCPoint(1.5, 1.75), CCPoint(1.9, 1.3) };
```

---

If you want to keep using this variadic function for some reason, you can stop the compiler complaining that you take the address of a temporary by not taking the address of a temporary.

You may be able to pass the objects by value, although as ecatmur pointed out this is implementation-defined (it should be ok if copy and move constructors and destructor are all trivial):

```
std::list<CCPoint> m = createPointArray(3, CCPoint(1.3,2.7),
                                        CCPoint(1.5,1.75), CCPoint(1.9,1.3));
```

(you already declared val as a CCPoint instance - rather than a pointer - in your function. Just change the va_arg type to match).

Otherwise, you could fall back on passing the double values directly:

```
std::list<CCPoint> m = createPointArray(3, 1.3, 2.7, 1.5, 1.75, 1.9, 1.3);

std::list<CCPoint> createPointArray(int count, ...) {
    std::list<CCPoint> arr;

    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl,count);
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {
        double x = va_arg(vl,double);
        double y = va_arg(vl,double);
        arr.push_back(CCPoint(x,y));
    }
    va_end(vl);

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Passing objects of class type via ellipsis is implementation-defined behavior and may not be supported; see 5.2.2p7.

Comment: Hmm, good point. I didn't give that alternative much thought, since it's clearly inferior anyway.

Comment: `std::list<CCPoint> l { {1.3, 2.7}, {1.5, 1.75), {1.9, 1.3} };`

Answer (score 1):

You just cannot take address of a temporary, exactly what error says. You can easily fix this by passing by value:

```
std::list<CCPoint> createPointArray(int count, ...) {
    std::list<CCPoint> arr;

    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl,count);
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
        arr.push_back(va_arg(vl,CCPoint));
    va_end(vl);

    return arr;
}

createPointArray(3, CCPoint(1.3,2.7), CCPoint(1.5,1.75), CCPoint(1.9,1.3));
```

And, you don't need such a function now:

```
std::list<CCPoint> arr {CCPoint(1.3,2.7), CCPoint(1.5,1.75), CCPoint(1.9,1.3)};
```

is much simpler

Comment: Passing objects of class type via ellipsis is implementation-defined behavior and may not be supported; see 5.2.2p7.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, just use `initializer_list`:

```
std::list<CCPoint> l { CCPoint(1.3, 2.7), CCPoint(1.5, 1.75), CCPoint(1.9, 1.3) };
```

In C++03, you may have an array and then initialize your list with:

```
const CCPoint points[] = { CCPoint(1.3, 2.7), CCPoint(1.5, 1.75), CCPoint(1.9, 1.3) };

std::list<CCPoint> l(points, points + sizeof(points) / sizeof(*points));
// or std::list<CCPoint> l(points, points + 3); // error prone
// or std::list<CCPoint> l(std::begin(points), std::end(points)); // In C++11
```